# Selenium Actions moveToElement not working for browserstack iphone only

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I'm writing a simple selenium automation for a Angular single page applcation and integrated the browserstack. This code run fine in locally, and works on browserstack for below platforms.

```
  - os: OS X
    osVersion: Big Sur
    browserName: Safari
    browserVersion: 14.1
  - os: Windows
    osVersion: 10
    browserName: Edge
    browserVersion: latest
  - deviceName: Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra
    browserName: chrome # Try 'samsung' for Samsung browser
    osVersion: 12.0
  - deviceName: Google Pixel 7
    osVersion: 13.0
    browserName: chrome
    deviceOrientation: landscape
```

But not working for iphones.

```
  - deviceName: iPhone 14
    osVersion: 16
    browserName: safari
    deviceOrientation: portrait
```

This is the code.

```
var act = new Actions(driver);
var target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label=\"nav-search-btn\"]"));
target.click();
act.moveToElement(target).build().perform();
```

Error for iphone is

```
The element identified by "5001" is either not present or it has expired from the internal cache. Try to find it again For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference Build info:
```

It says element 5001 not present or expired. But it cannot be happenned because I could click it in previous line.

I could capture the internal API calls that sends to browserstack also.

This is for click, this works fine.

```
POST /session/xxx/element/5002/click {
  "id": "5002"
}
```

This is for the moveToElement.

```
POST /session/xxx/actions -- {
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": "default mouse",
      "type": "pointer",
      "parameters": {
        "pointerType": "mouse"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "duration": 100,
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "type": "pointerMove",
          "origin": {
            "ELEMENT": "5002",
            "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "5002"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems the issue only occurs for moveToElement only and for iphones only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the moveToElement please try to incorporate the mobile:scroll method:

```js
RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.findElement(By.className("XCUIElementTypeTable"));
String elementID = element.getId();
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", elementID); // Only for ‘scroll in element’
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", scrollObject);
```

I hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried this but the same error still coming.